# How to provide AuthHttp angular RC4 Since provide is depricated

Tags: angular

In previous version I was providing AuthHttp as Fallows:

```
return bootstrap(<any>App, [
    // These are dependencies of our App
      ...FORM_PROVIDERS,
      ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
      ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
      provide(AuthHttp, {
          useFactory: (http) => {
              return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                  tokenName: 'jwt'
              }), http);
          },
          deps: [Http]
      }),
      provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/' })
  ]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

But in RC4+ provide is deprecated and deprecation warning is coming.
So how to change these compatible for later version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing changed to passing an object rather than a function:

```ts
return bootstrap(<any>App, [
    // These are dependencies of our App
    ...FORM_PROVIDERS,
    ...HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ...ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    ...ENV_PROVIDERS,
    { 
        provide: AuthHttp,
        useFactory: (http) => {
            return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
                tokenName: 'jwt'
            }), http);
        },
        deps: [Http]
    },
    {
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
        useValue : '/' 
    }
]).catch(err => console.error(err));
```